# How to force the image and video to fit inside the div without changing aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I force the image and video to fit inside the div without changing aspect ratio?

[image]

This is the html that gets rendered and I am using bootstrap to keep my website responsive.

```
        <div id="micropost-208">

          <div class ="jumbotron" style="background-color: #FFF; max-width: 100%; background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-position:center;border-top-left-radius:0px;border-top-right-radius:0px;">

            <div class="row paddingleft paddingright" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0">

              <div class="col-md-12 wordwrap">

                <p><p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Hello everybody</strong></p><p>A topic that I discussed within 45 seconds . I want to tell you now about it . As it deserves more time . The topic was '' One individual can have a great impact on a group or community . Select one person, explain how this person has affected the others in the community .</p><p>My husband , the doctor who had to work for two years in a village far away near Turkey , had a great impact on the people living there . Those people didn't use to send the girls to school . Moreover by age 11-12 girls there should be prepared to get married . So you can imagine a wife , house wife and a mother at age eleven or twelve . But Safa , my husband ,succeeded to stop this phenomena . It took him time to convince people there to let the girls attending schools and continue studying at university . Safa was able to change that community .</p><blockquote> I don't forget that scene in 2003, while I was looking out of the window I saw many girls wearing their beautiful blue uniform with their school bags on their backs .</blockquote><p> So people there greatly affected by the doctor who lived with them for two years 2002- 2003 . At that time , People in this village started to buy satellites which was forbidden and they started to use technology and see the world inside their homes.</p><p><img src="http://pixabay.com/get/b084a9b1131ffb76a9da/1432159599/vulture-708783_1280.jpg"></p><p><br></p></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I do not have access to the content inside the `<div class="col-md-12 wordwrap">`

I only have access to these divs.

```
    <div id="micropost-208">

      <div class ="jumbotron" style="background-color: #FFF; max-width: 100%; background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-position:center;border-top-left-radius:0px;border-top-right-radius:0px;">

        <div class="row paddingleft paddingright" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0">

          <div class="col-md-12 wordwrap">
```

I have tried setting `max-width="100%"` style and `img-responsive` class to all the above divs and it has no effect on the img tag.

Comment: `max-width="100%"; max-height="300px";` should contain it as long as the parent div has constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Twitter Boottrap you can give the class `img-responsive` please refer to http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
```

Or you can also do it with CSS `max-width: 100%;`

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="max-width: 100%;" />
```

Or in your style sheet (suggestion by Useless Code in the comments)

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

If you don't define height it will maintain the aspect ratio.

**with jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('img').addClass('img-responsive');
});
```

this will add the class img-responsive to all the images

Comment: I do not have access to the img tag. It is retrieved from the database and displayed.

Comment: @LovingRails you can probably use the`max-width` method without altering the HTML, instead of using a `style` attribute just add it your CSS with a selector that will target the images you want to scale.

Comment: @LovingRails you can use javascript, updated my answer to accomplish it with jQuery

Comment: suggestion by @UselessCode is what i'd choose as it will work without JavaScript, updated answer to include that as well :)

Comment: @aharen Jquery solved the problem but stretched certain images in other sections of the pages. I modified the jquery to add class img-responsive only to images within a div with a specific id. I assigned an id mposts to parent div and added this jquery. $('#mposts img').addClass('img-responsive'); Works fine. Kindly let me know if the jquery is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#micropost-208 .col-md-12 img {max-width: 100%;}
```